# PHP - AJAX - why is file access sequential - No Sessions

Tags: php, apache, session, ubuntu, locking

I have a php file that acts as a gateway to an application server. The php file acts as a connector, it collects values from the request and opens a socket to send a msg to the application server, and the echoes back the returned response - generally some HTML.

The process works correctly, however an individual user can only send requests in serial manner. Multiple users can access the same file.

I have noted other questions/comments similar to this and understand the points made - that when sessions are used the session file is locked and a request must finish before another request can be serviced. In our case sessions are not started automatically and the php code does not start a session.

So I am confused as to why I cannot execute multiple calls to the same file.

As a footnote PHP used with IIS 7.5 does not exhibit this behaviour.

session.save_handler = files
session.auto_start = 0

The environment is 
Ubuntu Server 10.04.4

PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 16:42:25

Comment: the file is being locked by the other processes

Comment: "by the other processes" - what other processes? Is seems to be fine if I run the request from Firefox and then concurrently from a Chrome session. So it is certainly a "session" related lock.

Comment: @Kylea It would seem that you are probably incorrect about there being no Sessions, then.

Comment: I did some testing and found that if the URL is made to be unique then simultaneous requests will get processed from the same client.

http://<servername>/path/connector.php/test_response?site_id=mysite&uniqueid=11111 and http://<servername>/path/connector.php/test_response?site_id=mysite&uniqueid=22222

So its not sessions its how Apache handles discrete requests from a browser. Need to drill a little more into what Apache is doing.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing and found that if the URL is made to be unique then simultaneous requests will get processed from the same client.

http:///path/connector.php/test_response?site_id=mysite&uniqueid=111‌​11 and http:///path/connector.php/test_response?site_id=mysite&uniqueid=222‌​22

So its not sessions its how Apache handles discrete requests from a browser. Need to drill a little more into what Apache is doing.